# deleting vector or pointers compiler error

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, compiler-errors

I have the following function,
used to work properly, however, I don't know what I did, I started to get some strange error

Container is a vector of pointers

```
template<typename Container>
void delete_collections(Container& c) 
{ 
    while(!c.empty()) 
    {
        delete c.back(); //<=== here
        c.back() = NULL;
        c.pop_back();    //<=== & here
    }
}
```

first error

****Multiple markers at this line**

- (Each undeclared identifier is
- `back' undeclared (first use this

second errro

- `pop_back' undeclared (first use

**solution**
I passed a map to the function by mistake once, I wish compiler gave any warning though.

Comment: What is the actual type of `Container`?

Comment: I send a vector of pointers

Comment: Looks like you instantiated the templated class with a Container that doesn't have back() and pop_back() methods.

Comment: how can I track, which function call causing this syntax error, I have lots of vectors, and way too many calls to this function

Comment: works for me with vectors. [see](http://ideone.com/HUfIG2)

Comment: @abdul Read your compiler errors they'll tell you where this is coming from.

Comment: @itwasntpete I'd totally up vote your solution if you put it in the answer.

Comment: the compiler error as exactly what I wrote, for some reason, I dont get a complete sentence. it through eclipse :/

Comment: How about the *whole* error messages? That said, this will work for vector, deque and list, but not for map, set and their unordered/multi variants. BTW, the assignment with NULL is unnecessary.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks, I knew that it isn't valid for a man; whole error messages isnt shown, I hate it. anyway I went manually, inspected every f-call, and found one used with a map :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, I would use a specialized container instead, take a look at e.g. Boost. Alternatively, store smart pointers where you don't have to call `delete` manually. Still, here's how to do it in a way that works with every container except maps:

```
template<typename container>
void delete_all(container& c) {
    for(typename container::const_iterator it=c.begin(), end=c.end(); it!=end; ++it)
        delete *it;
    c.clear();
}
```

With C++11, you could use `auto`, too, instead of `typename container::const_iterator`.

Comment: C++11 makes it easy! `for(const auto& v : c) delete v; c.clear();`

Comment: @abdul Just to clarify, the problem was they you were not dereferencing your iterator, so you were trying to delete your iterator, which is not a pointer, which you can't do. But yeah, use a container of std::unique_ptrs, which has the added bonus of working when you erase things as well.

Comment: I don't think that was the problem, rather that he was assuming an unordered sequence interface in his template function. When instantiated with e.g. map, the interface isn't there, so it doesn't compile.